# Changing password does not terminate other sessions?

Tags: bug

I logged in on Chromium (Linux) a long time ago. On MS Edge, a few days ago, I changed the password and logged in with the new one right after successfully.

However, changing the password did not terminate the session on Chromium and indeed I haven't (yet) entered the new password, as if I were still using the old one - how come?

Comment: I did this recently as well. Mobile chrome + pwd change in tablet's Firefox... I'm actually adding this comment from a session opened prior to changing my password. ;-)

Comment: What exactly becomes invalid about the old session when you change your password? It is still a session that was the result of a valid authentication. Who cares that it was done with an older password?

Comment: @Gimby I guess it's fine as long as it's you: what if someone stole your account? You'd change your password, but they would still have access.